# Tried every method but struggling to convert the values of a dataframe to the values of a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am new to pandas and I have googled every possible way to convert the values of dataframe columns to the values of dictionary.

My dictionary is very long, it has a length of 812274. And my Dataframe's shape is (18518404, 3), with columns (Index(['Disease', 'Symptoms', 'Counts'], dtype='object')). The first thing I did was to work only with the first 5 rows so I sliced the dataframe to give me a shape of (5, 3). The reason I did this was because my laptop kept crashing and also I wanted to verify that my code will work on the first 5 rows before applying it to the 18518404 rows.

The dictionary consists of something like the following

```
d = {4000001: 'butanol', 4000002: 'liver disease', .....}
```

so the keys are integers and the values are strings (a sentence or word).

My truncated dataframe has the name df_cofreqs_decoded_rows and looks like this:

```
    Disease     Symptoms    Counts
0   4011685     4016539     241
1   4246943     4800357     7129
2   4111112     4150317     648
3   4111112     4150319     163
4   4001178     4037495     106
```

with

```
df_cofreqs_decoded_rows.info()
```

I get the following information:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------       --------------  -----
 0   Disease      5 non-null      int64
 1   Symptoms     5 non-null      int64
 2   Counts       5 non-null      int64
 3   str_disease  5 non-null      int64
dtypes: int64(4)
memory usage: 288.0 bytes
```

My goal is to convert the 'Disease' and 'Symptoms' columns, which are codes that correspond to  keys in d into two new separate columns with their associated values from d. So if I consider the first row, for code: 4011685 and code: 4016539, this should represent the keys in d, which will give me their associated values and so on and so forth. Thus my dataframe should look like this (just showing the first row)

```
    Disease     Symptoms    Counts     Disease_str     Symptoms_str
0   4011685     4016539     241          Cancer           Diabetes
```

Therefore, in the dictionary d, 4011685 (key) was Cancer (value) and 4016539 (another key) was Diabetes (another value).

The first thing I did as I don't know how to apply it to both columns, so I am showing the code for the "Disease" column only was the following:

```
df_cofreqs_decoded_rows['Disease_str'] = df_cofreqs_decoded_rows['Disease'].apply(lambda x: d[x])
```

However, I get the error:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

So I consider changing the code to:

```
df_cofreqs_decoded_rows['Disease_str'] = df_cofreqs_decoded_rows.loc[df_cofreqs_decoded_rows['Disease']].apply(lambda x: d[x])
```

However, get a different error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([4011685, 4246943, 4111112, 4111112, 4001178], dtype='int64')] are in the [index]"
```

I really don't understand what I am doing wrong. I have also tried to use `.map(d)` or `.replace({'Disease': d})` rather than `.apply(lambda x: d[x])` but I still do not seem to have those integer values which represent the keys in d, to yield their corresponding string values from d.

I would appreciate any help please and I would also appreciate it if you can show me how I can apply the code simultaneously to both columns rather than doing it separately.

Answer (score 1):

1.) You are getting a `SettingWithCopyWarning` due to you working with a subset as a test.  If you worked on the whole frame this wouldn't be an issue.  I wouldn't be too concerned.

2.) Your second attempt is passing the applied results to a indexer which is Apples to Oranges.  An indexer is looking for the slice or index/column names, not the actual results.

A simple way to achieve what you need is:

```
keys = ['Disease', 'Symptoms']
df = df.join(df[keys].applymap(d.get).rename(columns={k: f'{k}_str' for k in keys}))
```

Result:

```
                              # mock d values
   Disease  Symptoms  Counts  Disease_str Symptoms_str
0  4011685   4016539     241  4011685_str  4016539_str
1  4246943   4800357    7129  4246943_str  4800357_str
2  4111112   4150317     648  4111112_str  4150317_str
3  4111112   4150319     163  4111112_str  4150319_str
4  4001178   4037495     106  4001178_str  4037495_str
```

---

Note that `applymap` might be considered a slower method.  If performance becomes an issue, you might try creating a frame out of your dictionary and then do a `merge` instead at the sacrifice of more memory taken:

```
s = pd.Series(d)
for key in ['Disease', 'Symptoms']:
    df = df.merge(s.rename(f'{key}_str'), how='left', left_on=key, right_index=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for having a look at my problem. I am applying the merge method, however, I seem to only get the 4 columns (Disease, Symptoms, Counts and Symptoms_str) rather than 5. Is it overwriting the keys in Disease?

Comment: It shouldn't, I'm getting the proper results - are you looping both `['Disease', 'Symptoms']` keys?

Comment: I am, Jupyter keeps killing my notebook so it never goes through, I will work on it and let you know. Thank you for the help :).

Comment: Since your data is relatively large, if you are running into memory usage issue you might consider recasting your `dtypes` to something else.  See: https://medium.com/@vincentteyssier/optimizing-the-size-of-a-pandas-dataframe-for-low-memory-environment-5f07db3d72e, your first columns in example could potentially be `int32` to halve your memory requirement.

Comment: I will try that, I really appreciate your patience and help :).

Comment: No worries, we're all here to help each other.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, if key is not found in the dictionary then return nothing:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=r'\s+')
d = {4011685: 'cancer', 4016539: 'Diabetes'}

def get_value(d, key):
    try:
        value = d[key]
    except KeyError:
        value = ''
    return value

df['Disease_str'] = df['Disease'].apply(lambda x: get_value(d, x))
df['Symptoms_str'] = df['Symptoms'].apply(lambda x: get_value(d, x))

print(df)

   Disease  Symptoms  Counts Disease_str Symptoms_str
0  4011685   4016539     241      cancer     Diabetes
1  4246943   4800357    7129
2  4111112   4150317     648
3  4111112   4150319     163
4  4001178   4037495     106
```

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful :). Would it be possible if you can kindly let me know why my first code using apply, did not work. I am still confused?